# Как проверить, отображается ли клавиатура Android в Appium на Java

Tags: java, android, appium

Нашел несколько фрагментов кода, где отображаются к Android Driver

```
boolean keyboard = driver.isKeyboardShown();
```

Но в моем случае такое не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно проверить?